# Recommender algorithm to recommend associated items

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am new to machine learning, but find it very interesting and something that I can see lots of applications for with our current product.  Please excuse any questions that may seem obvious.

I have a scenario whereby I would like to provide recommendations.  For simplicity sake, imagine I have database tables that hold Purchase and Purchase Item records.  Each Purchase Item describes the quantities, description (shoes, pants, shirts) and then total price of each item that the app presents to the user for purchase.  Often times, a Purchase Item or a series of Purchase Items related to a specific Purchase will automatically trigger the addition of other associated Purchase Items for similar type Purchases (maybe they want to add hats or gloves).

It's to be noted that there is no category assigned to these types of items.  They may be completely unrelated except they are applied together on Purchases on a regular basis (shirts, food, and cameras are unrelated but may be purchased together frequently).  That is, this is the purchasing habit of the user rather than (recommend hats because they are a type of clothing like shirts).

I experimented with Recommender algorithms, but don't fully understand how to apply it in this case.  Is this the correct algorithm I should be looking at?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Matt

Comment: What you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

For recommendation engines a lot of alternatives exists. Most of the people working on online shops use hybrid ones which combine a collaborative filtering model (system that tracks user preferences about products and learns from these preferences), combined with a content based algorithm which basically recommends products based on their specs.
[Here is a nice article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/quick-guide-build-recommendation-engine-python/) about the theory and some code to start with.